# How to detect if the UrlReferrer is spoofed in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, spoofing

In my website, I'm trying to check the UrlReferrer and I must not provide service to this request if it is not a valid address according to my repository.
Now here is the point, if the client spoofs this URL, how can I detect that this UrlReferrer is spoofed or know the original one in order to stop navigation to the next pages of my website?
I've developed my websites in ASP.Net web forms and ASP.net MVC.

Any suggestions will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should not base any form of security around the referrer, it's too easy to spoof. Additionally, you can't always rely on the referrer being sent in the header at all.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Sorry would you please suggest me a solution as an alternative to check UrlReferrer?how can I make sure that the request is coming from the actual source?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to prevent a user navigating to a source before they've completed some other process, then you could store some variable in the session or pass a parameter that indicates this first process has been completed. Otherwise, you may need a more robust authentication process than simply finding out where a request has come from.